# Attributes of a class instance not importing from a separate file

Tags: python

So I'm working on a text-based game in base Python, and I've encountered a problem. When I use my instance of the player class from the main file in another file, it doesn't save the attributes, for example the name.
Here's the relevant code.

`main.py`:

```
from ply import Player

player = Player()

...

def pickName():
    global player
    print("And, what's your name?")
    player.name = input(">")
    print("Hello, %s!" % player.name) #this works
```

`ply.py`:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ""

....
```

person.py:

```
import main

print(main.player.name) #prints an empty string
```

If there's any clarifying questions, feel free to ask; this is my first question here.
Thanks!

To address some concerns, pickName is called within main.py, so it does run and change the name within main.py, but not outside of it.

Comment: You haven’t called `main.pickPlayer()` in your `person.py`, so it’s not surprising that the name isn’t set.

Comment: well, you never call `pickName`. As an aside, you should really avoid global mutable state, that is one of the main reasons for classes.

Comment: `pickName` should call `Player` itself (passing the chosen name as an argument to an appropriate `Player.__init__`), then return the new instance.

Comment: I think you should create your player class with a name already, so ```def __init__(self, name)``` and ```self.name = name``` would be a much cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. Basically, I moved the instance of the class to the file in which the class is defined, and just imported the instance. Now, it works for some reason. If anyone knows why, please comment, but for now it works so I'm not going to complain.